# What is the best way to exclude object instances from a QuerySet in Django (filter() not an option in this case)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

Right now the best solution I can think of is to individually use queryset.exclude(pk=instance.pk) on specific instances.

The scenario is that I need to filter a model queryset for a few fields but then also check to see if a date field matches a given value. Normally I would just filter for date=mydate but in my case I need to calculate the date first using a stored timezone in a different model (which is why it seems like I can't simply use a filter)

Right now my code (which works but seems like a hack-y way of filtering) looks something like this:

```
user_tracks = HabitTrack.objects.filter(user=user)
filtered_user_tracks = user_tracks
for t in user_tracks:
    if not HabitEvent.objects.filter(user=user, track=t, date_expected=t.get_timezone_corrected_datetime_now().date(), post__isnull=True).exists():
        print("Excluding ", t.track_name, " with track specific time of ", t.get_timezone_corrected_datetime_now(), "from the list of options")
        filtered_user_tracks = filtered_user_tracks.exclude(pk=t.pk)
    else:
        print("Including ", t.track_name, " with track specific time of ", t.get_timezone_corrected_datetime_now(), "in the list of options")
```

For context, this is a snippet from my ModelForm so that I can limit form choices to only options available to the user "today" where "today" is calculated based on the user's timezone.

(This is also my first time asking a question on SO, so I will do my best to clean up my question if clarifications are needed, thank you!)

In HabitTrack model:

```
def get_timezone_corrected_datetime_now(self):
    return datetime.now(self.timezone)
```

Comment: Can you please show the code and any new models involved in `HabitTrack.get_timezone_corrected_datetime_now()`?

Comment: @schillingt I have added the code for the method to my post as you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be tough. `django.db.models.functions.TruncDate` with `functions.Now` might work, but I don't know if the timezone can be changed with an `F` instance. If you know a user's tracks are all in the same timezone, that makes things easier. Otherwise, for the short-term you may have to denormalize `HabitEvent.date_expected` so that you have the full datetime and the localized date.

Edit:

### Better Answer

You could also create your own Func instances using the database's functions. If you're using postgres, `timezone(zone, timestamp)` ([docs 9.9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html)) may do what you need.

Your func may look like this:

```
class LocalizedNow(Func):
    function = 'timezone'
    template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s, NOW())'
```

Then you could use it in the query with:

```
HabitEvent.objects.filter(expected_date=LocalizedNow('track__timezone'))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I don't have enough rep to upvote yet but I do appreciate it!